# How can I change the text value of an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I'm trying to change some properties of a status-bar that I'm using (HTML) and the only part I couldn't change was the following:

```
<div class="progress-bar" id="progress" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50%</div>
```

The 50% (between the brackets) is the value that I'm trying to change.

Currently I have the code:

```
$("#progress").attr("style", "width: " + percentagecontract);
$("#progress").attr("aria-valuenow", percentagenumber);
$("#progress").val(percentagecontract);
```

The third line is the line I'm trying to achieve the change. The variable percentagecontract is already returning the right value (at the test moment 65%).

The other 2 lines could change the values I needed, only this one is missing.

Comment: Divs don't have a value attribute

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm pretty new to programming so i'm mostly trying to figure everything out by myself, didn't knew that.

I realized that i can change that with the .text method!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved via the `.text()` method like so:

```
$("#progress").attr("style", "width: " + percentagecontract);
$("#progress").attr("aria-valuenow", percentagenumber);

// $("#progress").val(percentagecontract); Remove this line

$("#progress").text('**' + percentagecontract + '%**');
```

For more information on the text method, see the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/text/).